# Mining a primecoin based currency (datacoin). How do I find out how much hash power im doing?

Tags: hash, datacoin

How do I find out how much hashing power am I providing to the network? What is the command to find it out?

Currently I see this: http://prntscr.com/2cd3zo

when I run:  **watch 'datacoind listaccounts & datacoind getmininginfo'**

Comment: Are you using gen=1?

Comment: yes im using gen=1 in .conf file. what does that stand for? and where can i get a list of possible config options there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your screen shot, in theory, you are contributing 808 hash per second (primepersec), but this may not realistic, though.

How you get that screen shot? That is the correct command.

If you are using Qt, click on help > debug window > console then enter getmininginfo at the bottom ">" prompt. type help for other command.

HTH